# cloud_firestore The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have flutter app,  [image: I have verified rules on Firebase side]

Any other idea what i can do

Answer (score 1):

Issue was appcheck was enabled , after disabling it , it started working